# Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory time span question

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to get a list of failed logic app runs over a set time period. I have tried a number of methods like calling the azure management API and the cmdlet Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory. These both seem to return a limitited set of results.

Any suggestions on how to get failed runs for a 14 hour time period would be greatly appreciated

What i have tried so far:

`Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory -ResourceGroupName "$ResourceGrpName"  -Name "$LogicappName" | Where-Object {$_.StartTime -gt $Hour})`

```
 $filter = "status eq 'Failed' and startTime ge $queryStartTime"

    $requestUrl ='https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/' + `
        $((Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.Id) + '/resourceGroups/' + `
        $resGroup + '/providers/' + $LOGIC_APP_PROVIDER + '/' + $($logicApp.Name) + '/runs?api-version=2017-07-01&$top=1&$filter=' + $filter;
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please mark it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get-AzureRmLogicAppRunHistory` essentially calls the same [**rest api**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list) with your second way, but by designed you could not pass any parameter to limit the number of items in the result, so you will at most get a default `30` items.

To call the api via powershell like your second way, you need to specific the `$top` parameter, it designs the the number of items to be included in the result, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list#uri-parameters). The `$top` has a `PageSizeLimit` of `250`, so in your case, you could just use `$top=250`. If your items are more than `250`, you need to make another call to the api in the [`nextLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowruns/list#workflowrunlistresult) of the response of the first api call.

It  should be like `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/joylogicapp/runs?api-version=2016-06-01&%24top=250&%24skiptoken=eyJxxxxx%3d`

[image]

So in short, if your items are more than `250`, you could not get all the items for a 14 hour time period, you could at most get **250 items for one page**, if you want to get all the items, make call to `nextLink`.